# What is the best data structure for keeping track of Cells I have entered in a maze

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, depth-first-search

Here is how I am implementing this right now, using HashMap

```
private int steps=0;
private LinkedList<MazeCell> breadCrumbs = new LinkedList<MazeCell>();
private HashMap<MazeCell, Boolean> visitedCells = new HashMap<MazeCell, Boolean>();
public int stepsToSolveMaze(MazeCell cell)
{       
    if (visitedCells.get(cell) == null)
    {
        visitedCells.put(cell, true);
        breadCrumbs.push(cell);
    }
```

I am using a recursive algorithm to find the number of steps to the end of a maze.  Before I try to take the next "step" I need to make sure I have not been where I would be stepping.  I feel like there is a better data structure than a HashMap full of nulls except for where I have been, but I have no clue really.  Does anyone know of a better Data Structure for this?

Comment: I think Set is good choice.

Comment: Are there loops in the maze?

Comment: I would agree after reading about it, but my choice for a HashMap was because lets say the Maze is 1000x1000, I could know in a relatively constant time whether nor not I have been there, because I would have a key to my answer to that, rather than having to iterate through an entire list.

Then I read a bit more and saw HashSet which uses HashMap to do what  I am doing but prettier!  Thanks!

Comment: @BrandonRossPollack You can use method set.contains("something"); to check whether you visited that node already or not.

Comment: A Graph data-struct sounds like the best struct for you.

Comment: @Zutty Yeah there are loops, that is one of the reasons I am keeping track of all cells I have been as well as a stack.  The idea is if I hit a dead end I can pop the stack to go back to find another direction from where I have been before that I haven't gone while still maintaining a list of where I've been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `HashMap`, you should use a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). The code will be easier to read. The performance are equivalent since an `HashSet`is backed by an `HashMap<E,Object>`.

```
private int steps=0;
private LinkedList<MazeCell> breadCrumbs = new LinkedList<MazeCell>();
private Set<MazeCell> visitedCells = new HashSet<MazeCell>();
public int stepsToSolveMaze(MazeCell cell)
{       
    if (!visitedCells.contains(cell))
    {
        visitedCells.add(cell);
        breadCrumbs.push(cell);
    }   
}
```

An `HashSet` *`offers constant time performance for the basic operations.`*

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first guy to comment said Set, so I looked up Hash types that implement it and came to the same solution!  You guys are a great help!

Comment: I am glad to help you. If it solve your problem, you should accept this answer. Your question will appear as answered.

Answer (score 0):

The current design is ok. If the number of cells is fixed, you can save cells in an array, and use bit vectors to indicate visited ones. For example, a 32-bit integer could represent 32 cells.

Answer (score 0):

How about just having a `boolean[][]` for the whole matrix?

If you're not dealing with too large matrices, I'd probably go with this option.

1000x1000 isn't that large and the whole matrix would take up around 1 MB storage ([implementation dependent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)).

The overhead of read / write should be less than using hashing. It's also useful to note that if you have a bad hash function performance of hashing could be terrible. The 2D array solution doesn't have this disadvantage.

A less storage intensive solution would be a `BitSet[]`, coming in at around 125 KB storage for the 1000x1000 matrix.

Note that you can have `null` values in either case (`boolean[]` or `BitSet` can be null) where you have empty rows / columns (depending on the implementation) to reduce storage space even more.

**Disclaimer:** The above numbers are just estimates, I ignored a few things.

Answer (score 0):

[Disjoint Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

It is the most efficient way to implement this kind of data structure.

In a nutshell what you do is create a 2 dimensional array of integers which represents your maze. Each row column in the array will be an x,y coordinate in the maze. The value present at a coordinate location will present the "set" that it is in.

So in your case if you have visited a location put a 1 at that location.

So if the coordinate is not visited it will contain 0.